# Merge audio of multiple movies by ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to merge 3 video files to one. my problem is that i can hear the audio only from 2. one of them is muted.

The command i did will show the 3 movies each one next to each other and should play the audio from the whole 3.

This is my query:

```
complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", tempPath1, "-i", tempPath2,"-i", tempPath3,"-filter_complex",
                        "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=green[a];" +
                        "[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b];" +
                        "[2:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=blue[c];" +
                        "[b][c]hstack=inputs=2,scale=iw/2:-2[bottom];" +
                        "[a][bottom]vstack=inputs=2,scale=ih*2:-2[video];" +
                        "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[audio];" +    // take audio first movie, take audio second movie and merge with 2 inputs
                        "[audio][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[audio1]",
                        "-map",                 // map of the video
                        "[video]",
                        "-map",                 // map of the audio
                        "[audio1]",
                        "-ac",
                        "2",                    // number of chanels
                        outputFilePath};
```

The result of this command is that i can hear only movies a and b.
Thanks a lot :)

**Edit**

I also tried this one:

```
complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", tempPath1, "-i", tempPath2,"-i", tempPath3,"-filter_complex",
                        "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=green[a];" +
                        "[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b];" +
                        "[2:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=blue[c];" +
                        "[b][c]hstack=inputs=2,scale=iw/2:-2[bottom];" +
                        "[a][bottom]vstack=inputs=2,scale=ih*2:-2[video];" +
                        "[0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[audio]",
                        "-map",                 // map of the video
                        "[video]",
                        "-map",                 // map of the audio
                        "[audio]",
                        "-ac",
                        "2",                    // number of chanels
                        outputFilePath};
```

**Another Edit**

After another investigation, i saw that he is not merging the last movie audio. Also if i have 4 movies, it merges 3 and you can't hear the last one.

log (too long - this is the last half of it):

```
10.417 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  102 fps=1.2 q=28.0 size=     344kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate= 662.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=122 speed=0.0495x    
16.670 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  103 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     361kB time=00:00:04.29 bitrate= 689.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=123 speed=0.0466x    
17.329 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  104 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     366kB time=00:00:04.33 bitrate= 691.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=124 speed=0.0467x    
18.067 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  105 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     368kB time=00:00:04.37 bitrate= 688.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=125 speed=0.0468x    
18.658 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  106 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     371kB time=00:00:04.41 bitrate= 687.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=127 speed=0.0469x    
19.275 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  107 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     384kB time=00:00:04.46 bitrate= 705.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=128 speed=0.0471x    
20.951 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  108 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     388kB time=00:00:04.50 bitrate= 706.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=129 speed=0.0467x    
21.619 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  109 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     390kB time=00:00:04.52 bitrate= 706.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=130 speed=0.0466x    
22.170 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  110 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     393kB time=00:00:04.56 bitrate= 704.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=132 speed=0.0468x    
25.697 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  111 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     408kB time=00:00:04.63 bitrate= 720.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=133 speed=0.0458x    
30.467 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  112 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     413kB time=00:00:04.67 bitrate= 723.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=134 speed=0.0441x    
31.884 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  113 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=     415kB time=00:00:04.69 bitrate= 723.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=135 speed=0.0437x    
32.360 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  113 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     415kB time=00:00:04.73 bitrate= 717.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=136 speed=0.0439x    
37.274 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  115 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     435kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate= 741.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=138 speed=0.0426x    
38.060 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  116 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     439kB time=00:00:04.82 bitrate= 746.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=139 speed=0.0425x    
38.779 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  117 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     441kB time=00:00:04.86 bitrate= 743.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=140 speed=0.0426x    
39.463 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  118 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     445kB time=00:00:04.90 bitrate= 742.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=142 speed=0.0427x    
40.074 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  119 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     458kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate= 753.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=143 speed=0.043x    
42.906 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  120 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     462kB time=00:00:04.99 bitrate= 758.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=144 speed=0.0422x    
43.884 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  121 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     464kB time=00:00:05.03 bitrate= 754.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=145 speed=0.0422x    
44.378 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  121 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     464kB time=00:00:05.07 bitrate= 748.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=146 speed=0.0424x    
52.351 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  123 fps=1.0 q=28.0 size=     481kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate= 768.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=148 speed=0.0401x    
55.804 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  124 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     485kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate= 768.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=149 speed=0.0394x    
56.404 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  124 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     485kB time=00:00:05.18 bitrate= 765.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=149 speed=0.0393x    
57.011 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  125 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     487kB time=00:00:05.20 bitrate= 765.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=150 speed=0.0393x    
57.549 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  125 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     487kB time=00:00:05.25 bitrate= 759.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=151 speed=0.0395x    
58.072 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  126 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     489kB time=00:00:05.27 bitrate= 760.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=152 speed=0.0395x    
03.052 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  127 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     504kB time=00:00:05.29 bitrate= 779.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=153 speed=0.0382x    
04.000 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  128 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     509kB time=00:00:05.33 bitrate= 781.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=154 speed=0.0383x    
04.841 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  129 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     511kB time=00:00:05.35 bitrate= 781.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=155 speed=0.0382x    
05.615 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  129 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     511kB time=00:00:05.39 bitrate= 775.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=156 speed=0.0383x    
06.627 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  130 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     514kB time=00:00:05.42 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=157 speed=0.0382x    
07.511 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  131 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     525kB time=00:00:05.46 bitrate= 786.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=158 speed=0.0383x    
12.298 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  132 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     529kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 789.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=159 speed=0.0382x    
12.306 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  132 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     529kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 789.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=159 speed=0.0371x    
12.814 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  133 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     530kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 792.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=160 speed=0.037x    
13.584 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  134 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     533kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 796.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=162 speed=0.0368x    
18.744 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  135 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     547kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 817.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=163 speed=0.0356x    
19.776 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  136 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     551kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 823.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=164 speed=0.0353x    
20.554 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  137 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     553kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 825.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=164 speed=0.0352x    
21.113 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  138 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     556kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 830.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=165 speed=0.035x    
23.823 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  139 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     570kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 850.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=165 speed=0.0344x    
24.546 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  140 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     574kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 857.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=165 speed=0.0343x    
25.038 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  141 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     576kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 860.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=165 speed=0.0342x    
29.407 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  143 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     591kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 882.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=166 speed=0.0333x    
32.181 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  144 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     595kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 888.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=166 speed=0.0327x    
32.721 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  145 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     597kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 891.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=166 speed=0.0326x    
37.640 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  147 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     613kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 915.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=167 speed=0.0317x    
38.409 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  148 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     617kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 922.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=167 speed=0.0315x    
38.954 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  149 fps=0.9 q=28.0 size=     619kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 924.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=167 speed=0.0314x    
43.249 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  151 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     638kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 952.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=168 speed=0.0307x    
44.711 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  152 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     642kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 959.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=168 speed=0.0304x    
45.362 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  153 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     644kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 962.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=168 speed=0.0303x    
47.986 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  155 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     658kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 983.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=169 speed=0.0299x    
51.033 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  156 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     663kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 989.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=169 speed=0.0294x    
51.644 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  157 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     664kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 992.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=169 speed=0.0293x    
52.227 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  158 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     667kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate= 996.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=170 speed=0.0292x    
55.997 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  159 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     679kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1014.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=170 speed=0.0286x    
57.421 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  160 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     684kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1022.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=170 speed=0.0284x    
57.968 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  161 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     686kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1025.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=170 speed=0.0284x    
02.301 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  163 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     704kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1051.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=171 speed=0.0277x    
02.318 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
03.129 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  164 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     708kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1058.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=171 speed=0.0276x    
03.135 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
03.791 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
03.804 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  165 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     710kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1060.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=171 speed=0.0275x    
03.818 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
10.434 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 3 times
10.436 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  167 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     728kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1087.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=172 speed=0.0266x    
11.139 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
11.140 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  168 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     733kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1094.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=172 speed=0.0265x    
11.148 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
11.654 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
11.655 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  169 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     735kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1097.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=172 speed=0.0265x    
11.660 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
13.730 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 4 times
13.732 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  171 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     750kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1119.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=173 speed=0.0262x    
14.493 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
14.495 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  172 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     754kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1125.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=173 speed=0.0261x    
14.510 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
15.764 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
15.768 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  173 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     756kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1128.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=173 speed=0.026x    
15.967 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
17.594 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 4 times
17.600 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  175 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     769kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1148.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=174 speed=0.0257x    
22.264 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
22.270 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  176 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     773kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1154.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=174 speed=0.0252x    
22.273 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
22.794 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
22.796 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  177 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     775kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1157.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=174 speed=0.0251x    
22.997 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
26.730 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 3 times
26.732 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  179 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     792kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1182.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=175 speed=0.0247x    
26.736 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
27.345 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
27.347 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  180 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     796kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1188.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=175 speed=0.0246x    
27.811 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
28.017 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
28.019 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  181 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     798kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1192.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=175 speed=0.0245x    
28.027 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
31.612 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
31.617 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  183 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     820kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1224.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=176 speed=0.0242x    
31.620 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
32.251 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
32.254 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  184 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     827kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1234.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=176 speed=0.0241x    
32.654 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
32.828 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
32.833 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  185 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     828kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1237.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=176 speed=0.024x    
33.093 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
38.362 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
38.363 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  187 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=1240.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=177 speed=0.0235x    
38.370 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
39.216 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
39.217 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  188 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.54 bitrate=1230.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=177 speed=0.0236x    
39.744 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
39.747 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  189 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.58 bitrate=1221.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=177 speed=0.0238x    
39.748 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
40.354 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 4 times
40.355 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  191 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.67 bitrate=1203.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=178 speed=0.0241x    
41.031 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
41.037 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  192 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.71 bitrate=1194.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=178 speed=0.0242x    
41.046 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
41.557 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
41.561 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  193 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.75 bitrate=1186.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=178 speed=0.0243x    
41.744 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
42.421 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 4 times
42.423 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  195 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.83 bitrate=1169.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=179 speed=0.0245x    
47.015 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
47.017 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  196 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.88 bitrate=1160.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=179 speed=0.0243x    
47.019 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
47.517 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
47.524 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  197 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:05.92 bitrate=1152.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=179 speed=0.0244x    
47.524 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
48.946 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 2 times
48.959 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  199 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=1136.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=180 speed=0.0246x    
48.961 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
49.797 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 1 times
49.798 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  200 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.04 bitrate=1128.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=180 speed=0.0247x    
49.803 Started command progress : ffmpeg Error while decoding stream #2:1: Out of memory
50.546 Started command progress : ffmpeg     Last message repeated 4 times
50.547 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  201 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.08 bitrate=1121.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=180 speed=0.0248x    
53.010 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  204 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.21 bitrate=1098.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=181 speed=0.0251x    
53.713 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  205 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.25 bitrate=1091.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=181 speed=0.0252x    
53.722 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  205 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.25 bitrate=1091.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=181 speed=0.0251x    
50.706 Started command progress : ffmpeg frame=  205 fps=0.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=     965kB time=00:00:08.46 bitrate= 933.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=181 speed=0.0277x    
50.720 Started command progress : ffmpeg video:872kB audio:87kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.621844%
50.720 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] frame I:1     Avg QP:19.09  size: 40991
50.725 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] frame P:51    Avg QP:18.16  size: 10789
50.726 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] frame B:153   Avg QP:19.57  size:  1966
50.729 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0% 99.5%
50.737 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] mb I  I16..4: 31.5% 61.8%  6.7%
50.742 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] mb P  I16..4:  2.3%  2.0%  0.1%  P16..4: 31.9%  5.7%  2.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:55.6%
50.750 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 18.2%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 1.0%  skip:80.3%  L0:46.2% L1:53.2% BI: 0.6%
50.753 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] 8x8 transform intra:49.4% inter:92.4%
50.754 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 19.1% 26.6% 3.8% inter: 2.5% 7.1% 0.0%
50.756 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 15%  5% 39%
50.764 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 14% 32%  3%  5%  5%  4%  4%  3%
50.767 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 20% 25%  2%  6%  4%  4%  2%  1%
50.768 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 20% 20%  4%
50.772 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
50.774 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] ref P L0: 54.0%  5.5% 29.8% 10.6%
50.776 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] ref B L0: 76.8% 18.5%  4.7%
50.777 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] ref B L1: 96.2%  3.8%
50.779 Started command progress : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] kb/s:834.67
50.898 Started command progress : ffmpeg [aac @ 0xf35ffc00] Qavg: 1539.341
50.960 SUCCESS with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/temp1.mp4':
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Duration: 00:00:05.55, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 191 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 360x360 [SAR 16:9 DAR 16:9], 113 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/temp2.mp4':
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Duration: 00:00:06.73, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 170 kb/s
        Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 360x360 [SAR 9:16 DAR 9:16], 90 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/temp3.mp4':
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Duration: 00:00:08.50, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 177 kb/s
        Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 360x360 [SAR 9:16 DAR 9:16], 97 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0xf38a7780] No channel layout for input 1
    [Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0xf38a7780] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
    [swscaler @ 0xf35f1000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    [swscaler @ 0xf35e6000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
    Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
    [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] using SAR=16/9
    [libx264 @ 0xf35ff400] using cpu capabilities: none!
    [libx264 @ 0xf3
50.966 Finished command : ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@7c54447
```

Comment: Works for me. Show the complete log from your second command. Because this is a question about using ffmpeg it would be easier for us lazy people if you provided unscripted ffmpeg commands that we can copy and paste for testing. Otherwise the scripting adds another layer of complexity and I may not bother to look at it. And of course always provide the log.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for you help. this is the command:
ffmpeg -i tempPath1 -i tempPath2 -i tempPath3 -filter_complex \
      "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=green[a]; \
      [1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b]; \
      [2:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=blue[c]; \
      [b][c]hstack=inputs=2,scale=iw/2:-2[bottom]; \
      [a][bottom]vstack=inputs=2,scale=ih*2:-1[video]; \
      [0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[audio]
      -map
      "[video]"
      -map
      "[audio]"
      -ac
      "2"
      outputFilePath

Comment: and this is the last lines of the logs:
 [Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0xf38a7780] No channel layout for input 1
    [Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0xf38a7780] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
    [swscaler @ 0xf35f1000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    [swscaler @ 0xf35e6000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
    Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using amerge to merge 3 mono inputs into a single 3 channel stream. ffmpeg interprets this as the 2.1 channel layout (FL+FR+LFE). The `-ac 2` option ignores Low Frequency Effects when downmixing to stereo, so the third channel is being dropped.

One method is to use the pan filter to manually perform the downmix. You didn't specify which input channels should go into which output channels, so this example just puts all of them in each output channel.

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=green[a]; \
 [1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b]; \
 [2:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=blue[c]; \
 [b][c]hstack=inputs=2,scale=iw/2:-2[bottom]; \
 [a][bottom]vstack=inputs=2,scale=ih*2:-1,format=yuv420p[video]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3,pan=stereo|FL<c0+c1+c2|FR<c0+c1+c2[audio]" \
-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

The `ffmpeg -layouts` output is useful when working with audio channels.

---

<sub>Unrelated to the issue: I assumed you want yuv420p output instead of yuvj420p so I added the format filter and also added `-movflags +faststart` since I'm guessing you're going to be presenting the video via progressive download.</sub>

Comment: It is working. you are awesome!
another small question, i want now to merge 4 audio from 4 movies, i tried this:
"[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo|FL<c0+c1+c2+c3|FR<c0+c1+c2+c3[audio]", 

but it is not working ( cant hear the last one).

Comment: command:
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=green[a]; \
 [1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=red[b]; \
 [2:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=blue[c]; \
 [3:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=yellow[d]; \
 [a][b]hstack=inputs=2[top]; \
 [c][d]hstack=inputs=2[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2,format=yuv420p[video]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo|FL<c0+c1+c2+c3|FR<c0+c1+c2+c3[audio]" \
-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart out.mp4

Comment: @S.T The log is missing but required. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: @S.T Maybe `Error while decoding stream #1:1: Out of memory` has something to do with it.

Comment: Ok. in another log when i am doing a different 3 movies merge with audio he says: No channel layout for input 1. 
What does it mean?